# My code in Visual Code is only showing up in blue and white?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I am scripting in C#, the text is only showing up in blue (computer commands) and white (everything else). However, when I see others' code, it has all sorts of colours and even autocompletes (which mine doesn't).

I've tried changing the font style and colour scheme, but it changed nothing.

This is what my code looks like:

[image]

This is what I want my code to look like:

[image]

Comment: Kudos for wanting to code using Comic Sans MS.

Comment: More seriously, Miscellaneous Files is visible which tell that you haven't you opened the solution but rather a .CS file directly, correct ?

Comment: I am using unity to open the scripts so I can only assume they open a .cs file directly @aybe

Answer (score 1):

From Unity navigate to: Windows > Package Manager

Then select Visual Studio Editor and update the package.

*Code editor integration for supporting Visual Studio as code editor for unity. Adds support for generating csproj files for intellisense purposes, auto discovery of installations, etc.*

Answer (score 1):

Within Unity navigate to: Edit > Preferences > External Tools

Find "External Script Editor" and in the dropdown box pick "Visual Studio"

Close the preferences window.

Within Unity navigate to: Assets > Open C# Project (Close all scripts)

Open scripts again and everything should be updated

Answer (score 1):

From what it seems like to me, what you're after is themes and autocomplete right? So I will go in order:

## Themes

Themes in Visual studio can be downloaded via the extensions page:

Extentions>Manage Extensions

Restart Visual studio

Tools>Options>Environment>General>Color Theme(Select the one that you installed)

Here just search for the one you want or any other extension! I personally stick to the default theme but with the "Enhanced syntax highlighting" extension.

## Auto Complete

This SHOULD come automatically if you have installed the "Game Development with Unity" workload in visual studio and have the "Visual Studio Editor" package in unity installed but if you still don't get autocomplete try installing the [.NET Core sdk](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download) and [.NET Framework 4.6 Targeting Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=48136)
Also from what it looks like to me, you have opened a single .cs file NOT an entire solution which would give you autocomplete! So go to use right-click on the project browser and select "Open C# Project"

Comment: Right! The color theme was the problem. I was thinking that there's another weird problem with omnisharp.